# derive the pdf for "difference of log-normal distributions"

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, logarithms, normal-distribution

Can someone please help me to derive pdf for $X$,
$$
X = \frac{\ln(f_1) - \ln(f_2)}{b_2-b_1}
$$
here $f_1$ and $f_2$ are normal distributions with different means and standard deviations, and $b_1$ and $b_2$ are constants. Ultimately, what I need is to find mean and standard deviation of $X$.

I'm not sure how this can be derived when both log and difference are involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A first point that is not very clear in your question:

- (1) are $f_1$ and $f_2$ random variables ?
- (2) or are they densities $f_i(x)=K_i exp(-(x-m_i)^2/(2 \sigma_i^2))$ ? In this case, it would mean a mixture of densities.

My answer works for case (1) and the very particular case where $f_1$ and $f_2$ are random variables following a $N(0,1)$ distribution.

$X$ can be written $k \ln(\frac{f_1}{f_2})$ where $k=1/(b_2-b_1)$ is a constant (assumed >0).

But $\frac{f_1}{f_2}$ follows a standard Cauchy distribution (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalRatioDistribution.html) with

$$\text{pdf :} \  \ f_C(x)=\dfrac{1}{\pi}\dfrac{1}{1+x^2} \ \text{and} \ \text{ cdf :} \ F_C(u)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\pi} atan{u} \ \ \ (1)$$

thus $X=k ln(C)$ with $C$ naving a Cauchy distribution. Thus the cdf of $X$ is

$$F_X(x)=P(X<x)=P(C<exp(x/k))=F_C(exp(x/k)) \ \ (2)$$

It remains to plug (1) into (2), then derive (2), in order to get its pdf.

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful. Sorry, I should have be more clear on $f_1$ and $f_2$. However, my problem falls into case (2). In that case, $f_i(x)=K_i exp(-(x-m_i)^2/(2 \sigma_i^2))$.

Due to the nature of the problem means $m_1$ and $m_2$ are nonzero, but standard deviations can be assumed to be $\sigma_1 = \sigma_2 = \sigma$.
what would you suggest me to work on in such case?

Comment: Are you really sure that your problem canot be formulated as "Let  $X_i$ be random variables that  follow a $N(m_i,\sigma_i^2)$ distribution, what is pdf of the random variable $k(X_1-X_2)$?". Otherwise interpretation (2) with a difference of pdf **does not make sense**: the difference of 2 pdf can for example be negative at some times, positive at others...

Comment: I think what you said makes more sense. I've been trying to represent my problem in statistical terms the best I could. I hope this might be more clear: $f_1$ and $f_2$ are random variables that follows normal distributions with non-zero means $N(m_i,\sigma^2_i)$. The Cauchy distribution works only when means are zero. In my case $m_i$ is non-zero for sure. Also, provided that $(b_2 - b_1) > 0$

Comment: Two (specialized) references: http://airccj.org/CSCP/vol4/csit43105.pdf  arxiv.org/pdf/1309.3057  Does it help ?

Comment: I read over those references. what they talk about is log-normal distributions; if $X$ is normal then $L = e^X$ is log-normal. here what I have is if $f_1/f_2$ is normal ratio distribution then what is $X = ln(f_1/f_2)$. what I'm saying is $ln(f_1)$ isn't log-normal.

Comment: However, I could find the pdf of normal ratio distribution for non-zero means on wikipedia [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution). Can you guide me how can I derive pdf of $X = kln(f_1/f_2)$ from there? Thanks.

Comment: I will more or less rewrite what I have given in the (inappropriate in fact) answer. Let $X=k ln(Q)$ with $Q$ (quotient of two gaussians) having a certain distribution function $f_Q(q)$ that I understand you have . A classical trick you surely have met is to reason on the cdf (cumulative dist. function, not pdf) of $Q$ is 
$$F_X(x):=P(X<x)=P(k ln(Q)<x)=P(Q<exp(x/k))=:F_Q(exp(x/k)) $$ Now we take the derivative with respect to $x$: $f_X(x)=f_Q(exp(x/k))(1/k)exp(x/k)$.